# Compare strings in WPF and highlight differences in Side by side window

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working in a [wpf](/questions/tagged/wpf) project in which I need to compare two strings and display in a side by side window with line number should be shown and differences must be highlighted with color.

I am new to [wpf](/questions/tagged/wpf) and I don't have any idea about completing this task.

Please help me.

Comment: I would like a never ending packet of _Tim Tams_.  Please don't post requirements.  Tell us about what research you have done.  What have you tried?  Any code?  _[Read the manual](http://stackoverflow.com/help)_

Comment: It's too broad! You are asking for an end solution that may have a million versions. It's better if you try to begin by yourself. Start with simple examples that cover one or two details in your main projects. Then, come here and ask for help when you are stuck. You will get great help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking at something like Syntax Highlighting of Text after comparison(or identifying the differences)? Below links might help you if you want to do simple highlighting of the text. The idea should be simple perhaps:

- Identify the Difference
- Find the start and end position of difference
- Highlight the difference only.

If you'd want to go for simple solution, check these link if they work for u:

- https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CSWPFSearchAndHighlightText-3b5e207a
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7c9a622a-4e3b-451e-bc4c-ab9d011447e0/texthighlighting-in-wpf-richtextbox?forum=wpf

Moreover, there are several controls available online for Syntax Highlighting in wpf. You can simply search for it. I came across Fast Colored TextBox on CodeProject once for similar requirement. Hope this helps.

I think this would be the generic advise I might be able to offer for a generic question like this. Or u may want to go a bit more specific about what type of content you are trying to highlight? Is it Rich text or plain text in a TextBlock? And as the comment above? Any research & considerations you've done? And any code to give an idea about the scenario?

Comment: Honestly I don't think it's that simple. Identifying the difference is more like applying the [Longest Common Subsequence Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem). The algorithm is key and the OP is already asking for a lot even without mentioning the fact that he probably knows very little about WPF and wants us to write the code for him.

Comment: You are probably right in citing the fact that LCS problem is none of a piece of cake. However, there are lots of developers who're sharing their code online so we never have to re-invent the wheel. Here is [one link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13326/An-O-ND-Difference-Algorithm-for-C) - it is very straightforward - just a single class Diff.cs to include. But this might work for simple scenarios. I agree that the information provided by OP is already too limited to make any specific suggestion.